# Django Rest Framework non-model serializer show selective fields

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to selectively display fields in my serializer. I do not have any Django model (use external resources). This is my serializer.

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    result = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        first_name = attrs.get('first_name')
        attrs['result'] = transform_only(
            filter_by_fn(first_name)
        )
        return super().validate(attrs)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('result',)
```

`First_name` is a `query_param`. 
`Result` is the only field I want to use in serializer to display. In `validate` method I download data for that field.

**My question is how can I display only some fields?** `Meta class` seems to not working (probably because of lack of model). I want also avoid ugly solution like `Response(data=serializer.data['result'], ...`

My `ViewSet`:

```
class FilterByNameViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = Employee2Serializer(data=self.request.query_params)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=200)
```

Comment: does your input contain `result` data?

Comment: It contains only `first_name`. `Result` is dictionary with external data filtered with `first_name`.